# Why Input onChange acts like onKeyDown in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

In the following example, the `onChange` event fires each time the user type in a letter (like the `onkeydown` event) is this the normal behavior?

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class Form extends React.Component {
  state = { name: '' };

  _handleNameChanges = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState({ name: target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          placeholder="John Doe"
          onChange={this._handleNameChanges}
          required
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is the normal behavior, what is happening is that as soon as the keyboard key is pressed, `onKeyDown` is triggered before the character is typed into the form field. `onChange` will only be fired if a combination of `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` happens. By stopping the propagation of either you will be able to not fire `onChange`

```
<input 
     onKeyDown={e => {e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault()}}
     onChange={e => console('never fires')}
/>
```

Comment: Very nice explanation, so how to achieve the default (old-school) `onchange` behavior?

Comment: This is the default behavior. The event gets triggered everytime the user press a key

Comment: @AhmedM.Kamal What do you mean with old-school behaviour? what behaviour are you looking for?

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez I mean the default `onchange` behavior like when you type in some value and the input loses focus (the event fires on blur not on keypress).

Comment: @Dupocas This is not the usual behavior of onchange (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange))

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can see more in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#onchange)

> The onChange event behaves as you would expect it to: whenever a form field is changed, this event is fired. We intentionally do not use the existing browser behavior because onChange is a misnomer for its behavior and React relies on this event to handle user input in real time.

Along with a few examples: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, React maps `onChange` to `onInput` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40003179/4965515)). Nonetheless, the solution is to use `onBlur` instead.