# Hidden input doesn't trigger React's onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom-events

I'm facing a weird issue with the input field in React. I'm aware of the fact that `hidden` input do not trigger `input` nor `change` events. However, even if I trigger them manually, React's `onChange` event is still not being invoked.

I trigger both, `change` and `input` event here because React's `onChange` is in fact the `input` event. When I setup an event listener on the `inputRef` (`addEventListener("change", () => { ... })`) for testing purposes, it's being called without without problems. However, it turns out React is having some issue intercepting it.

Here is my current code:

```
const [fieldValue, setFieldValue] = useState(0);
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

const handleClick = useCallback((): void => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
        inputRef.current.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", { bubbles: true }));
        inputRef.current.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }));
    }

    setFieldValue(prev => prev + 1);
}, []);
```

JSX:

```
<input type="hidden" ref={inputRef} value={fieldValue} onChange={(e) => { console.log("React:onChange"); }} />
<button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Hit it</button>
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? What else do I have to do to properly trigger React's `onChange` event?

Comment: would be nice if you can put it in codesandbox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Detect value change on hidden input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533087/jquery-detect-value-change-on-hidden-input-field)

Comment: Why do you need the `ref`? It looks like your `fieldValue`is in the state, you should set the new state in the `onChange` and when clicking in the button simply get the current state value, it will hold the current input value

Comment: @KryštofŘeháček How does these relate? I trigger changes, not looking for solution how to do that.

Comment: @quirimmo I will be using `ref` for other purposes like the HTML5 validation and stuff like that hence I need to access the DOM object.

Comment: Set a validation flag with `useState`. When the state has changed run the validation check then update the flag. You don't need a ref.

Comment: @Andy Well, as I said, that isn't my only motivation. Using `ref` has an advantage of registering multiple listeners (eg. you can't have several `onChange` in React, for instance - you have to merge them) and altering input without re-renders, which is great for my needs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Events in React are handled by react-dom, through different plugins. Input events are managed with the **SimpleEventPlugin** (see https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-dom/src/events/SimpleEventPlugin.js)

This plugin gets an event and redispatches it without interfering too much. So you can dispatch it as a native event, and it'll be triggered as a **SyntheticEvent** without much changes.

Change event is handled by the **ChangeEventPlugin** (see https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-dom/src/events/ChangeEventPlugin.js). This plugins has this purpose:

> This plugin creates an `onChange` event that normalizes change events
>   across form elements. This event fires at a time when it's possible to
>   change the element's value without seeing a flicker.

The plugin triggers change event but not exactly as the native change event. The native change event on text input element for example is triggered only on blur. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

> For some elements, including , the change event
>   doesn't fire until the control loses focus.

But with React, it's triggered differently, on every change of value. To do this, it is handled by the plugin which has these restrictions:
The event will be triggered only on these input types:

```
  color: true,
  date: true,
  datetime: true,
  'datetime-local': true,
  email: true,
  month: true,
  number: true,
  password: true,
  range: true,
  search: true,
  tel: true,
  text: true,
  time: true,
  url: true,
  week: true
```

So on hidden inputs, react stops the dispatch.

Another restriction is that the event will be dispatched only if the value of the input actually changes. See

```
 if (updateValueIfChanged(targetNode)) {
    return targetInst;
  }
```

So even on a supported input, your dispatch won't go through the plugin. You can see it in this snippet, by manipulating a method that is used to get the value of the input you can manage to dispatch the event.

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();

  }

  componentDidMount() {
  //_valueTracker.getValue is used for comparing the values of the input. If you write fake value in the input it'll dispatch, anything else won't
    document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0]._valueTracker.getValue = () => {
      return 'fake value'
    }
  }

  render() {

    const handleClick = () => {
      if (this.myRef) {

        this.myRef.current.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", {
          bubbles: true
        }));


      }
    };

    return <div > < input type = "text"
    ref = {
      this.myRef
    }
    onChange = {
      (e) => {
        console.log("React:onChange");
      }
    }
    /><button type="button"  onClick={handleClick}>Hit it</button > < /div>

  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Hello name = "World" / > ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

So for a hidden input, there's no way to make it work (note that it is in line with the standard). For a text (or other supported inputs), you can but you need to more or less hack the method comparing the value before the event with the value after the event.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I've been fighting for. Thanks for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The onChange event is fired [when the user alters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) the element value - in your case, you are programmatically changing the input value and hence `onChange` is not firing up

`onInput` [events fires](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) when value changes - regardless how. Therefore you need to add `onInput` even listener instead of `onChange`.

```
<input type="hidden" ref={inputRef} value={fieldValue} onInput={(e) => { console.log("React:onChange"); }} />
```

Here is a working example: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-tdd-80vwp)

Comment: `in your case, you are programmatically changing the input value and hence onChange is not firing up` Correct, but don't forget that I'm also triggering the `change` event manually. Should work fine then. `onInput` wont work too if not the manual trigger in my code. Odd enough, because React `onChange` is an actual `input` event ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40003179/7043033)).

Comment: if your input is hidden, there is no chance that your `onChange` will be triggered because as specified in the docs which I linked, onchange event handler is trigger only when user alters it. No one cal alter it if its hidden right?

Comment: I don't think this is actually true. Change the input type to `text` and React's `onChange` will never be called as well. Also, manual trigger works in Javascript as I said: simply add the event listener to the `inputRef.current` to verify it works and gets called when triggered manually. The problem must be React-specific then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be approaching this the wrong way. When you click the button you want the state to update and that new state reflected in the hidden field. Instead of checking the change in the hidden field you should be checking the change in the state which you can do very easily with [`useEffect`](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/). That way you can do away with your refs and not over-complicate things.

```
function App() {
  const [fieldValue, setFieldValue] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    setFieldValue(prev => prev + 1);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
     console.log('React:changed');
  }, [fieldValue]);

  return (
    <>
      <input type="hidden" value={fieldValue} />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Hit it
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-burnell-e9ogp)