# How do I add event listener 'on change' to an input element with React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In React, `onChange` in the following code is regarded as an `on input` event handler, not `on change`, if I understand correctly:

```html
<input onChange={() => ()}></input>
```

But I *do* want to handle `on change` events. How do I do that?

**Updates**:

In React, `onChange` will be triggered on [input events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event), so it cannot handle [on-change events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) (for `HTMLInputElement`).

I want to handle on-change events, not on-input events.

Comment: Check this out if that helps : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256332/in-react-whats-the-difference-between-onchange-and-oninput

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is a duplicate question, but I certainly think the above link will get you straightened out.

Comment: Yeah, I know what the answers to the link say (as I mentioned), but that does not give any answer to 'how to handle (literally) on-change events.'

Comment: What do you need to do? Do you just need a working example? https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Above link says that there are no differences between `on input` and `on change` in React's point of view, while they are different in the DOM's world. I want to handle `on change` of the input element in DOM's sense (*not* in React's sense).

Comment: For `on change`, I mean this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event But `onChange` in React is triggered on input events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Comment: See my updated question.

Comment: Ok, so nearly all of my JS/web development experience has been in React, so this distinction makes no sense to me. It's clear though that React handles `onChange` events a specific way. What does the React `onChange` handling not do that you are wanting?

Comment: Oh, I see. So there should be some alternatives. Hmm `onBlur` might do what I want. Ok, I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although they are not *exactly* the same, `onBlur` handler does what I would like.