# onChange is not called when typing `e` in number input in React and Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I found a strange behaviour when working with input fields with `type="number"` in React. I have a really simple React component with one controlled number input field and as `e.target.value` is always a string, I am parsing it to make it a number.

```js
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const input = e.target.value;
    console.log(input);
    const parsedValue = parseInt(input, 10);
    console.log(parsedValue);
    setValue(isNaN(parsedValue) ? input : parsedValue);
  };
  return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="number"
          min={1}
          max={100}
          value={value}
          pattern="\d+"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </form>
  );
}
```

The `handleInputChange` function is called every time I enter a new value input, but it is not called when I type characters `e`, '+', or `.`. For the `+`, `.`, and `-`, I understand that we expect some digit after that so calling onChange doesn't make much sense but for the `e`, it should have called onChange.

I tried to simulate the same behaviour with vanilla javascript but there `change` event is only called if I increase/decrease the number using arrow keys. Here is the [codepen example for the same][1]

Can someone explain this behaviour and how can I detect typing `e` in number input?

Edit:
I think there is some confusion with this question. I want to understand two things about `change` event behaviour for number input fields.

1. Why React doesn't call `onChange` when I type `e`, '+', '-', and '.' ?
2. Why `change` event is not called when I type some value in input in Vanilla Javascript?
   [1]: https://codepen.io/aditya81070/pen/WNjoLao

Comment: I am not familiar with reactjs, but generally the `input` event is more practical here (at least in Vanilla-JavaScript), as it is fired immediately anytime anything changes in the input element.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking why number inputs work one way in React/JSX? Or why they work differently in vanilla HTML/JS? What are you really asking for?

Comment: No @DrewReese, I mean that in both React and Vanilla Javascript, when we enter `e` , the change event is not called.

Comment: The OP has 2 doubts one why is onChange not triggered with e in react and 2nd why is onChange not having correct e.target.value in native JS with e. Correct?

Comment: Yes @TusharShahi.

Comment: `e` by itself isn't a valid number yet, but is part of a valid number, i.e. `1e2` is the value `100`, so `e` alone isn't enough to trigger an input change. React fundamentally handles inputs differently than HTML/JS.

Comment: See [difference between onChange and onInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256332/in-react-whats-the-difference-between-onchange-and-oninput)

Comment: Thanks, @DrewReese. Got it. If I want to prevent entering these characters the only way is to prevent typing these characters as I see in other SF answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any text ending with e is not a number.
It is like `1e3` or `2e4`.
So if your number is ending with `1e`, it is not valid. Javascript is preventing you from doing so that is why both in your native code and in react, although the onChange(/onchange) is triggered the `e.target.value` is "". So you can not make use of it.

Comment: Yeah this was answered by @DrewReese in the comments. The same thing happens with `+`, `-`, `.` . Also, I had another question about the onChange difference in React vs Vanilla Javascript and @DrewReese shared an answer for that.