# How to make onChange only fire once value is changed in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I'm using a range input in my React application. I would like to log the value selected once the range slider has changed (not while it is changing). Here is an example of my issue:

```js
const App = () => {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.valueAsNumber);
  }
  return <input type="range" onChange={handleChange}/>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

If you view the browser console, the value is being logged as you slide the range slider. My desired output is so that the `handleChange` callback is only fired once you release the slider. I would like it to behave in a similar way that onChange behaves in vanilla HTML:

```js
const handleChange = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.valueAsNumber);
}
```

```html
<input type="range" onChange="handleChange(event)"/>
```

It seems like react has made `onChange` behave like `onInput`, which in my case is undesirable. Is there a simple prop that I'm missing to make this work? Or do I need to use refs or some other method to make this work as intentded?

Comment: have you tried `onMouseUp` ?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar - Thanks, `onMouseUp` could work, and I might try going with that. However it would have issues if users use `tab` to select the range input and then use the arrow keys `<` and `>` to change the slider.

Comment: would `onFocusOut` help?

Comment: Set onChange from ref like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62383569/11218031

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar looks like onFocusOut doesn't work in React. But maybe a combination of `onMouseUp` and `onBlur` could also work.

Comment: yeah, you could make both `onMouseUp` and `onBlur` trigger the same functions

Comment: @AvinashThakur thanks - I'll take a look at that. I was hoping that there would be a standard inbuilt prop to retain the standard vanilla behaviour of onChange, but looks like there isnt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour you want is of [onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) event listener. Unfortunately, React connects onChange prop to [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) event handler.

There's also an active issue about this: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3964 [Document how React's onChange relates to onInput #3964](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3964)

Simple fix would be to use onchange event listener using ref.

```js
const NewInput = (props) => {
  const setRef = useCallback((el) => {
    el.onchange = props.onChange || null;
  }, [props.onChange]);
  return <input ref={setRef} {...props} />
}
```

Another approach is discussed here: [In React, what's the difference between onChange and onInput?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62383569/11218031)