# Round the value by step in number input

Tags: reactjs

I have a number input:

```
const [NumberVal, setNumberVal] = useState(5);

<input 
   type="number" 
   value={NumberVal || ''} 
   min={5} 
   max={50}
   step={5}
   onChange={event => setNumberVal(Math.round(event.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/, '') / 5) * 5)} 
/>
```

I want to round the value as per the step, but every time I enter the value as input, I get a value of 5, i.e. I cannot specify less or more than 5. I always get only 5, or 55555...

In vanilla JavaScript this works fine:

```
Math.round(event.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/, '') / 5) * 5
```

but not in React.

Comment: What does `setNumberVal` do?

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's the react hook way of updating the value (which will then trigger a render). Yeah, react has to do it it's own way, as usual.

Comment: If you are already rendering with a react state, what is the point of doing `event.target.value =`? Calling `setNumberVal` will already update the output, so are you doubling up? And does `setNumberVal` also return the value you passed in (Its been a while since I worked with react)?

Comment: @somethinghere, Yeah. That doesn't make sense. I've updated the code.

Comment: And that doesn't change anything I guess? How about using `event.target.valueAsNumber` instead? That would eliminate the regex you are using that might create strings?

Comment: @somethinghere, No, that doesn't help - `valueAsNumber`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onChange` triggers your 'convertFunction' so the value is instantly overwritten.

You'll need to *debounce* the input so you'll wait for the user to finish their input.

---

A simple debouncer can be done with `onBlur`, so update normally `onChange`, but when the user leaves the input (or use a timeout), call your `convertFunction`.

---

##### Demo using `onBlur` and `onChange`

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [NumberVal, setNumberVal] = useState(5);
   
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <input 
               type="number" 
               value={NumberVal} 
               min={5} 
               max={50}
               step={5}
               onChange={event => setNumberVal(event.target.value)} 
               onBlur={() => setNumberVal(p => (Math.round(p.toString().replace(/[^\d]/, '') / 5) * 5))}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

##### Demo using `onChange` and a `setTimout` to delay 1000ms

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [NumberVal, setNumberVal] = useState(5);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const debounce = setTimeout(() => setNumberVal(p => (Math.round(p.toString().replace(/[^\d]/, '') / 5) * 5)), 1000)
        return () => clearTimeout(debounce)
    }, [NumberVal])
   
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <input 
               type="number" 
               value={NumberVal} 
               min={5} 
               max={50}
               step={5}
               onChange={event => setNumberVal(event.target.value)}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

Regarding the comments about using `onInput`, the following Stackoverflow answer suggest it's the same effect as `onChange`:

- [In React, what's the difference between onChange and onInput?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256332/in-react-whats-the-difference-between-onchange-and-oninput)

If the `onBlur` does not give the desired result, I'd go with the `setTimeout` way.

Comment: Good catch, although `onChange !== onInput`, and `onChange` would only trigger when the input loses focus or the user presses the enter key, no? In. which case the debouncer isn't necessary? Or is react doing something special?

Comment: Nope, `onChange` triggers instantly when a key is pressed. Imo this is most user friendly when the input html can't be changed.

Comment: So it _is non-standard behaviour_ that React implements contrary to spec. That's not how inputs are supposed to work, and exactly the reason there are two types of events in vanilla JS. But in that case your answer will work. (to see what I mean, try `<input type="number" onchange="console.log('change')" oninput="console.log('input')" />` and see what happens when you are typing. Why does React change that?)

Comment: Yea, well the onChange call is expected I guess, it's just not smart to overwrite a user input with a new value, that's weird ux.

Comment: It does kind pf make sense as an input doesn't actually correct the value while you type, which is why you should only do that on the `change` event and not the `input` event, to correct for the fact you are allowed to enter any number in a number input, and the `step` only applies when you press arrow keys or the like.

Comment: Yea but inserting the '1' of '19' is still considered a change right? And thus `1` will be passed to the convertFcuntion

Comment: No, in plain HTML/JS, that is not the case. The `change` only gets triggered if you blur the input or press enter or the like. Seriously, just create a new snippet and run `<input type="number" onchange="console.log('change')" oninput="console.log('input')" />` and see - `input` will trigger _as you type_, but `change` will only trigger when you are finished. But again, maybe React does it differently for unknown reasons, so if that's the case then your answer would work/solve the issue.

Comment: @0stone0, thanks for the reply. can `onInput` be used instead of `onBlur`?

Comment: I've tried that @s.kuznetsov but I'm not able to get the expected behaviour with `onInput`, feel free to extend my answer if needed.

Comment: I;ve added some explaining about the `onINput`, hope that makes it more clear @s.kuznetsov.

Comment: So it is a _react_ thing. Sigh, how stupid. Perhaps you could just `{ref}` the element and attach the event listener to the change event manually instead of using JSX/Reacts built-in binding to the `input` event for onChange? How incredibly stupid though.

Comment: Yea using a ref could fix this, but I wont recommend using refs when they can be avoided. There are also some debounce npm packages for react if you want to make it more readable by using a custom hook.

Comment: Did my answer helped @s.kuznetsov? Please upvote/accept for further readers ;)